# Full chain certificate on SAML SP metadata

Tags: xml, certificate, saml, x509

Sorry for my English since I'm not a native speaker.

I'm doing federation as SP for 3rd party IdP and I need to include the full chain certificate, but it gives me the error MSIS3014, Not valid certificate.
The problem is the third party doesn't trust my intermediate certificate and I can't install it on their machine.

I tried to include all certificates into the metadata xml through 3 different nodes X509Certificate but it still gives me the error.

I need an example of full cer chain in SAML metadata for make this work.
Tried to find but couldn't.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge there is no specification published which defines how a certificate chain has to be represented in the SAML meta data. [The SAML meta data interoperability profile](https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/Post2.0/sstc-metadata-iop.html) only specifies that every certificate has to be placed in a separate `<md:KeyDescriptor>` element. You may need to engage with your third party's SAML implementation vendor, to find out how they handle things.